# Need help troubleshooting Bottom Sheet Dialog button and autocomplete text view in Android Java

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I created a Bottom Sheet Dialog But Any Functionality that I put their Wont Work ,

> For Example I put An Autocomplete Edit Text View but wont get any Suggestions
> 1,I made an Array In the Activity I am Working in but it is still not Working
> 2.I Put my Suggestions in the Strings file and Referenced then to the Edit Text View But it Didn't Work

I Created a Button on The Bottom Sheet Dialog But it Wont Even Reflect a Toast Message On Being Clicked

What Should I Do?????
I Desperately Need Help

I tried Restarting my Laptop it didn't Work
[Bottom Sheet Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62iVC.png)